# Problems with the chatterbot (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the library chatterbot (python), but the computer's terminal gives me  this error: "could not build wheels for preshed, thinc, blis, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects".

I tried to upgrade all the python's library and python, too. I tried to search a slotion, but i don't find one. Can someone helps me?

Comment: Welcome! What is your python version?

Comment: Hello, my python version is 3.11.8

Answer (score 0):

chatterbot only supports till `python 3.8`

You need to install `python 3.8` separately to work on chatterbot.

https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/

[image]